# Javascript class method returning array but not assigning it to a new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have the following code

```
var Datos = function(){
    this.salas  = ['something','other'];
}
Datos.prototype.getSalas = function(){
    return this.salas;
}
```

Then, If I do

```
var datos = new Datos();
var myArray = datos.getSalas();
```

Why "myArray" var is now a function and not an array?
How can I convert to an array this variable?

Comment: This is a good page for `Javascript` functions - http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html

Comment: console.log(myArray) print ["something", "other"]

Comment: It works fine. What are you getting?

Comment: This works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/onk1Lnzz/

Comment: console.log(myArray) print function Datos.getSalas()

Comment: @dac777 Not with the code you've posted. `var myArray = datos.getSalas` without the `()` now, that would be a different matter

Comment: I'm going to check again the code...

Comment: @RGraham this was the problem. Thank you very much. I forgot the ()

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
var Datos = function(){
    this.salas  = ['something','other'];
}
Datos.prototype.getSalas = function(){
    return this.salas;
}

var datos = new Datos();
var myArray = datos.getSalas();

console.log(myArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v558tzbj/

Comment: Ditto... datos.getSalas (vs datos.getSalas()) would be an array, OP, is it possible that's what you are calling?

Comment: is working for me now. I forgot the () ... datos.getSalas instaead of datos.getSalas()